# SQL: Select column as <another column's value>

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table

```
ID | LanguageID | Text
1  | 1          | Abc
1  | 2          | Def
```

I want to select data so that all rows with the same ID are grouped into one row and each text is selected into a column with the name of its LanguageID. In this particular example the result would be

```
[ID: 1, 1: 'Abc', 2: 'Def']
```

Can this be done? How? Thank you

I am using MySQL.

EDIT: Seems like the easiest thing to do is to write a script to merge the rows outside of the database.

EDIT2: I don't know what answer to accept since none works or meets the requirements above.

Comment: Is `LanguageID ` is limited or dynamic ??

Comment: LanguageID is dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a fixed number of language ids, then you can do this as:

```
select id,
       max(case when LanguageId = 1 then text end) as "1",
       max(case when LanguageId = 2 then text end) as "2",
       max(case when LanguageId = 3 then text end) as "3"
from t
group by id;
```

If you don't know the language ids in advance, then you need to use dynamic SQL to construct the query and then prepare and execute it.

If languageid is dynamic:

```
select @s = concat('select id',
                   group_concat(concat(', max(case when LanguageId = ',
                                       LanguageId,
                                       ' then text end) as "',
                                       LanguageId, '"'
                                      )
                               ),
                   ' from t group by id'
                  )
from (select distinct LanguageId from t) t;

PREPARE stmt1 FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

Comment: So there is no way how to do this dynamically in SQL?

Comment: Any example  if languageid is not known or it is dynamic ?

Comment: Gives me several errors: 
Error in query (1583): Incorrect parameters in the call to native function 'concat'
Error in query (1064): Syntax error near 'NULL' at line 1
Error in query (1243): Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt1) given to EXECUTE
Error in query (1243): Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt1) given to DEALLOCATE PREPARE

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, group_concat(languageid), group_concat(text)
from t
group by id
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/159927/1)

or

```
select id, group_concat(languageid, ':', text)
from t
group by id
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/159927/7)

Comment: I need separate columns.

Comment: The OP wants the result set should look like this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/159927/11 but hasn't confirmed that languageid is dynamic or not

Answer (score 0):

```
     select id, group_concat(languageid,':', text) as result
     from table1
     group by id
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/abd66/5)

Comment: The OP want `languageid` as the alias and under this alias text will be listed

Answer (score 0):

Check this out hope this is what you're looking for: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/159927/13

```
    select id, group_concat(concat(languageid, ' ',text))
    from t
    group by id
```