# SQL Server name a column with AS using another column's selected value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to use a selected result as a new column name. For example:

```
SELECT 
[Table1].ID,
[Table1].OptionOneValue AS [Table2].OptionOneName,
[Table1].OptionTwoValue AS [Table2].OptionTwoName,
[Table1].OptionThreeValue AS [Table2].OptionThreeName,
FROM [Table1]
INNER JOIN [Table2] ON [Table1].ID = [Table2].ItemID

| ID         | Screen Size | Cost         | Service Date |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|:------------:|
| 1001       | 1920x1080   | NULL         | 11-25-19     |
| 1002       | 2048×1080   | 400.00       | 11-26-19     |    
| 1003       | NULL        | NULL         | 11-26-19     |   
| 1004       | NULL        | NULL         | 11-27-19     |
| 1005       | 2048×1080   | 500.00       | 11-27-19     |
```

- **OptionOneName** = Screen Size
- **OptionTwoName** = Cost
- **OptionThreeName** = Service Date

This will not work, it throws a syntax error. This is the closest other question to what I am asking: [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18044423/sql-select-column-as-another-columns-value)

Comment: You would need to make use of dynamic sql to get this working, as column_names have to pre-defined in the parse phase of the query processing

Comment: Can only be achieved through dynamic query; however in most cases may not be recomendable for something like this. Eg what will happen to your results if the join returns many-to-many, what should be the column name then, and how to use it? I would reassess what the problem is you try to solve and then write a different script to solve that accordingly